# Stored procedure slowness in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

When I am executing a stored procedure with some inputs, it took more than 30 seconds to run, but when I directly execute the query with the same inputs, that only took 3 seconds.

I guess it's due to the poor execution plan that stays in the cache, so first I dropped that stored procedure and recreated it, but that did not work. So I added a `WITH RECOMPILE` option to the stored procedure and tried but that also does not work.

Then I tried to assign the input parameters to local variables and then used those local variables inside the stored procedure (instead of the actual parameters) and after that, the execution time of the stored procedure is reduced to 3 seconds (if it's due to parameter sniffing then `WITH RECOMPILE` option will also resolve it right!).

And even I restored the same backup in another server and then executed the same stored procedure with the same inputs it took only 3 seconds.

So can someone please clarify the logic behind it?

Comment: Any chance you can include the stored procedure creation code?

Comment: I've had to assign local variables in the past. I never had much luck with using "WITH RECOMPILE." Assigning local variables has always solved the issue though. Always assumed it was parameter sniffing.

Comment: Yes that is classic parameter sniffing. You can read more about it, why it happens, how to fix it etc.....[here](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2007/11/27/parameter-sniffing/). Make sure you read all 3 parts.

Comment: You can use `sp_whoisactive @get_plans =1` while it is executing to see if the plans are different. It'll also give visibility into other operations on the server that may be hogging resources. Note: SQL Server does not come with `sp_whoisactive` but it is free to use.

Comment: Are your stats up to date? Did you try the OPTION(RECOMPILE) query hint, or only at the proc level? I would expect the OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN) to behave the same as local variables.

Comment: How do you call the stored procedure? Is it perhaps from .NET or some web server or...?

Comment: Suggest you read Erland's discussion on [slow in app, fast in ssms](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)